# Print all posts inside a 3x3 grid with Bootstrap and Jekyll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

I’m trying to create a grid with Bootstrap 4 that contains my posts in a 3x3 grid.

My code now is:

```
<div class="col-sm-8" id="main-content">

  <div class="row">

    {% for post in site.posts%}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="../media/logo-prueba.jpg">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h4>
          <p class="card-text">{{ post.category }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

  </div>
```

The first div with col-sm-8 is just there because I’m also using a sidebar.

How can I approach this? Like printing in a row 3, then in the next one 3, and the last on 3?

The output is this one with **3** posts:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="../media/logo-prueba.jpg">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">test1</h4>
          <p class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="../media/logo-prueba.jpg">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Otro post!</h4>
          <p class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="../media/logo-prueba.jpg">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Calzón chino</h4>
          <p class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that `site.posts` actually contains 9 posts? Can you dump the value?

Comment: @fubar In fact I had 2 only, and it only printed 1. But now I added 3 more and prints them, except for the very first one, which I don't get now too. I'll edit my question now.

Comment: Post the output when you dump `site.posts` value.

Comment: @fubar done, check the post.

Comment: If you output the value of `site.posts.size`, what do you get? Are all of the posts published (i.e. date in the future)?

Comment: @fubar it outputs 3, but I checked the date and indeed one was not 'published'. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162708/discussion-between-dawn-and-fubar).

Comment: Awesome. I couldn't see anything wrong with the code you were positing, so thought it would be something obvious that's easily overlooked.

Comment: I would also add clearfixes after 3 items, using the modulo function in Liquid (to prevent strange stacking behaviour when the first or the second item is higher than the third).

Answer (score 1):

Setting a fixed inline width to a bootstrap element who's parent has a percentage width is not the way to go, as it will break the responsive behaviour. By default, the card element takes up all available space in your column. If you want it to be smaller, use a margin on the card and not a fixed with (rem equals an amount of pixels). Make sure the image width is (still) 100%.

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:9 %}
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="../media/logo-prueba.jpg">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h4>
      <p class="card-text">{{ post.category }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Finally, as suggested in the comments, use modulo to prevent strange stacking behaviour when the first or the second item is higher than the third:

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:9 %}
  {% assign indexmod3 = forloop.index | modulo: 3 %}
  {% if indexmod3 == 0 %}<div style="clear: both;"></div>{% endif %}
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```